# Google Developer Sheets API Javascript Quickstart Uses Deprecated gapi.auth2

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

The Google Developer Sheets API for Javascript has a great quickstart:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

My application is based on this and has been good for years. However, the quickstart uses gapi.auth2 which is to be deprecated.

Source: Migrate to Google Identity Services: https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis

This guide states that "if using the API Client Library, remove the deprecated gapi.auth2 module, its methods and objects, replacing them with Identity Services equivalents."

Does anyone have a similar quickstart, but which uses the new Google Identity Service?

I have attempted to follow the migration guide, however it's beyond my ability to create something that works.

Particularly difficult for me is the section that states:
Previously, Google Sign-In helped you to manage user signed-in status using:
....
You are responsible for managing sign-in state and user sessions to your web app.

Answer (score 0):

They did it!
Here's the updated quickstart:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

Here's the commit:
https://github.com/googleworkspace/browser-samples/pull/87

Terrific

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31709562)